# Язык и наречие

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нередко в литературных текстах встречаю слово "наречие", употребленное в значении "язык". Допустимо ли это? Ведь "язык" и "наречие", по-моему, разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

В лингвистических словарях наречие (кроме значения 'части речи') определяется именно как язык, говор, местный или социальный диалект. То есть не общеупотребительный язык, а язык ограниченного употребления. Скажем, в диалектологии наречие - наиболее крупная единица членения языка, совокупность диалектов, объединенных общими признаками (Лингвистический энциклопедический словарь).